# MinionPro, newtxmath and further misadventures with oldstyle and lining figures

Tags: math-mode, fonts, oldstylenums, minionpro, newtxmath

In continuing [my journey](/questions/128767/libertine-newtxmath-and-text-oldstyle-figures-in-headers) with the `newtxmath` package, this time I've tried the next code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[lf,onlytext]{MinionPro}% no osf, no math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[minion,vvarbb,cmbraces,cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pmnj} % use osf in text

\begin{document}
\noindent
Text figures: 0123456789
\par\noindent
Math figures: $0123456789$
\end{document}
```

This appears in the documentation for `minion2newtx`. My problem is that when I pdfLaTeX the code above, what I get is the Latin Modern fonts (or Computer Modern) for text mode, and MinionPro for math mode. The line to blame for this is that one setting the roman typeface to `pmnj`. If I comment the corresponding line, I get everything Minion, but text figures are lining, while what I want is lining figures for math mode and oldstyle for text mode. I believe my system (MikTeX 2.9 updated just today) has the right settings and all the necessary fonts files, but maybe I'm skipping something.

A second issue is that if I use MinionPro in math mode, not loading `newtxmath` and deleting the option `onlytext` when loading `MinionPro` I get the wrong glyphs for at least some of the operators. Maybe this has something to do with the first problem, but I really don't know.

Could someone provide some hints as to what's happening? Maybe it's just something about my own MikTeX setup, but so far I haven't been able to find anything wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, after seeing that my question did not get to enjoy much popularity, after delving into the fonts files in my MiKTeX setup, and after trying unsuccessfully with `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{MinionPro}` on the basis of the folders found therein and of the content of my `updmap.cfg` file, I took a look at the style file `MinionPro.sty` itself. What I found there proved useful and it turned out to go in the same direction as the answers provided to my quest in the link I set on this OP. The following works (I got rid of everything but the essential lines in the preamble):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[lf,onlytext]{MinionPro}% no osf, no math
\usepackage[minion]{newtxmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\Mn@Text@Fig}{OsF}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{MinionPro-\Mn@Text@Fig} 
\makeatother

% The above can be compressed to
% \renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{MinionPro-OsF}
% but in the former coding it mirrors the way 
% that the selection is defined in the package.

\begin{document}
\noindent
Text figures: 0123456789
\par\noindent
Math figures: $0123456789$
\end{document}
```

At first I was reluctant to provide an answer to my own question on this site, but then I thought it might turn out to be useful to somebody. Moreover, it looked nice to me in that it is somehow "consistent" with the approach to the same issue when choosing to typeset with the Libertine family and `newtxmath`.

Comment: This information provided in the `minion2newtxdoc` to use `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pmnj}` appears incorrect. Have you notified the package author?